# How to see appengine quota percentage in billing enabled app?

Tags: google-app-engine, quota

In free appengine apps you can see the datastore reads and writes usage quota as a percentage of the free quota, along with the absolute number (approximated to the 0.01 million ops).

The percentage values gives a more accurate view of the currents usage (at least apparently, the percentage values seem to be accurate to one percentual point). Whereas if you calculate the percentage for the absolute values you would only get accuracy to 20 percentual points.

On billing enabled apps you only get to see the absolute values, which provide only a very coarse approximation of the current usage. Is there any way to get the more accurate percentual view in billed apps?

I need this for a profiling study of my app where I run it during a ten hour period under different loads and then read the quota usage...